# Jmeter keeps failing

Tags: tomcat7, jmeter

I have a simple web application that checks the price of books. The web application is called books. I am using Jmeter to test some performance aspects about my application. I have created a thread group in which I have a simple controller in which I have a sampler Http request. I have the following tree in Jmeter

```
Thread Group
   Simple Controller 
      Get Books
```

In the get books I pass in the following values in the parameter(price)  and the value is 40

When I run the tests I get this error message

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 1970-01-01 10:00:00 EST
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1098
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1098
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1

    Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    Response message: Non HTTP response message: protocol = http host = null

    Response headers:


    HTTPSampleResult fields:
    ContentType: 
    DataEncoding: null
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. The tomcat server is running the application works fine. I am really new to Jmeter so not that good with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Server name, port number, method and path are correct. Do not add http:// in server name.

If the method is GET, try to access the url through browser and check response is same.

Check if all the request headers are handled.

Comment: legend I figured it before you posted this but I will give you thumbs up anyway.